# C# object to class

Tags: c#

I can't get it to work to cast an object to a class...
I need that because i dynamically load a Dll and give it the class as parameter of a method. The class is linked in both projects (same file).

My Class I want to give to the Dll:

```
public class CParams
{
    public int m_iFunctionCode = -1;

    public STTestDll pTestDll;
    public struct STTestDll
    {
        public int m_iSleepTime;
        public int m_iCount;
    }

    public string GetDescriptionText()
    {
        return "Starte Dll: Sleeptime=" + pTestDll.m_iSleepTime.ToString() + "; Count=" + pTestDll.m_iCount.ToString() + "; Solldauer=" + 
            (pTestDll.m_iSleepTime * pTestDll.m_iCount / 1000).ToString() + " Sekunden";
    }

    public CParams(int iFunctionCode_)
    {
        m_iFunctionCode = iFunctionCode_;
    }
}
```

The call of the DLL:

```
Type typeDll = asmDLL.GetType(strClassName + "." + strClassName);
object activator = Activator.CreateInstance(typeDll);
MethodInfo miRun = typeDll.GetMethod("Run");
if (miRun != null)
{
    CParams pParam = new CParams(0);
    pParam.pTestDll.m_iCount = 200;
    pParam.pTestDll.m_iSleepTime = 25;
    object[] args = new object[1];
    args[0] = pParam;
    miRun.Invoke(activator, args);
}
```

The Code which tries to cast the class:

```
public void Run(object objParams)
{
    CParams pParams = (CParams)objParams;
    MessageBox.Show(pParams.pTestDll.m_iCount.ToString() + " - " + pParams.pTestDll.m_iSleepTime.ToString());
}
```

The Error is: InvalidCastException.

Comment: It seems to me that both methods know the eventual type, why would you rely on method invocation and casting? This rather seems like a place where abstraction over interfaces would be lots more help to you?

Comment: you're saving `GetMethod` in a variable called `miRun` but you're checking `m_miRun` for `null` - is that a typo?

Comment: I just changed the code before posting and didnt changed that. Ive corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar scenario I had the same problem. In my case I had two assemblys:

- The executable
- Dll

The implementation of the refference I wanted to pass over was in the DLL and my Executable had the DLL added as reference. Bot assemblys knew about the Implementation and the code would compile. But when executed I got that invalidCastException. The solution to my problem was an additional DLL, in which to put the implementation of my reference class (in your case CParams) and then link refer to that DLL in both other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Just because both assemblies use the same file content, doesn't mean it is in the Type.

The runtime sees two CParams classes are two totally different types. You cannot cast between them.

You need to put it in an assembly that is referenced by both.